# Custom Laravel Auth not working properly

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, password-recovery

I've created my own routes to login:

```
    Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Route::get('/registrar', [
    'as' => 'clubRegistrar',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister'
]);

Route::post('/registrar', [
    'as' => 'clubPostRegistrar',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'
]);

Route::get('/ingresar', [
    'as' => 'clubIngresar',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'
]);

Route::post('/ingresar', [
    'as' => 'clubPostIngresar',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin'
]);

Route::get('/salir', [
    'as' => 'clubSalir',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout'
]);
```

There's only something missing, **Password reset**.

My problem right now is with the **login** routes, the get method is ok, it works, but the post method doesn't work properly, it authenticates the user, but it doesn't redirects to another route or path... Something curious is that it works well with the default view, but if i use my own view, it doesn't...

Here's my **AuthController**

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    private $loginPath = '/ingresar';
    private $redirectTo = '/reservacion';

    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->registrar = $registrar;

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    public function getRegister()
    {
        return view('Club.auth.register');
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        return view('Club.auth.login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $inputs = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $credentials = array_merge($inputs, ['type' => 1]);


        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
            ]);
    }
}
```

And here's my custom view:

```
<section class = "store-checkout" >
        <div class = "container wow fadeInDown" >
            <div class = "row" >
                <div class = "col-md-12" >
                    <div class = "container" >
                        <div class = "row" >
                            <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 wow fadeInDown" >
                                <div class = "contact-form-contaienr" >
                                    <div class = "section-title" >
                                        <h1 ><span >Inicia Sesion</span ></h1 >
                                    </div >
                                    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'clubPostIngresar', 'action' => 'clubPostIngresar',
                                     'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'contact-form', 'role' => 'form' ]) !!}
                                    {!! Form::token() !!}
                                    {!! Form::email('email', old('email'), ['autocomplete' => 'off', 'placeholder' => 'E-Mail*','required']) !!}
                                    {!! Form::password('password', ['placeholder' => 'Contrasena']) !!}
                                    {!! Form::submit('Ingresar!',[]) !!}
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    <div id = "form-messages" >
                                        @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                            <strong >Whoops!</strong > Hubieron unos problemas con tus datos.<br ><br >
                                            <ul >
                                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                                    <li >{{ $error }}</li >
                                                @endforeach
                                            </ul >
                                        @endif
                                    </div >
                                </div >
                                <!-- /contact-form-container -->
                            </div >
                            <!-- /col-md-6 -->
                        </div >
                        <!-- /row -->
                    </div >
                    <!-- /container -->
                </div >
                <!-- /col-md-12 -->
            </div >
            <!-- /row -->
        </div >
        <!-- /container -->
    </section >
```

### UPDATE August 22, 2015

I solve the problem with the submit button at login, it was a jQuery configuration.

Now my question turn into **Password Reset**, how do i make the custom route for it?, I know it's handled by PasswordController, but do i just have override the methods from `ResetsPassword trait` in `PasswordController` ? Can someone make an example?

Comment: btw, nice clean code. do you have a reservaion route defined?

Comment: Thanks @mdamia, yes i have a `reservacion` route defined, i got it working right now, it was a jquery config the one that was making the problem, I'll update the post, i need to know about the **reset password**

Comment: What error is thrown when you try to make a route for your password reset?

Comment: It works, but when trying to send the email i get `cannot send message without a sender address`